# PackageMaker Custom UI Dialog

Tags: packagemaker

I'm using PackageMaker to build an installer package for my OS X application.  I need to customize the dialog that the user sees when installation fails (return non-zero value from post install script).  The Edit Interface dialog in PackageMaker does not list the error dialog.  Is there a way to manually modify the PackageMaker project to customize this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PackageMaker donot give functionality to change the UI. You can only change the message that U want to show to the client. Almost non of the third party installer give the functionality to change the UI.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: I think you have to post question in serverfault. Because it is not programming related

Comment: is it possible to change the error string without changing the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, at least from the PackageMaker UI.